# Unital $C^{*}$ algebras whose all elements have path connected spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

A unital $C^{*}$ algebra is called a "Path connected algebra" if the spectrum of all its elements is a path connected  subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

> **What is  an example of  a  non commutative path connected  $C^*$ algebra? What is an example of a simple path connected  $C^{*}$ algebra? In particular does $C^{*}_{red} F_{2}$ satisfiy this property?**
>
> As another question: Is the tensor product of two path connected algebra, a path connected algebra?(For spatial norm).

Comment: An easy example: $C(X)$ for some path connected compactum $X$ is path connected in this sense because the spectrum of $f\in C(X)$ coincides with the range of $f$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn  But $C(X)$ is not simple.

Comment: Oh you meant simple as in simple not as in easy...

Comment: @JohannesHahn yes I mean without closed two sided ideal.

Comment: Well $\mathbb{C}$ is simple. But I assume you want something less trivial. A stab in the dark: One could imagine putting some group action on $C(X)$ such that none of its non-trivial ideals are $G$-invariant and hope that $C(X)\rtimes G$ is simple.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Thanks for your  comment. If I am not mistaken, this algebra is simple iff the action of $G$ on $X$ does not have  a nontrivial compact invariant set. Now how you controle the spectrum of elements?

Comment: The spectrum of a nontrivial projection (i.e., nonzero and not the unit) is disconnected. Thus, a unital C*-algebra with the property you consider cannot contain any nontrivial projections. Conversely, if a C*-algebra contains a normal element with disconnected spectrum, then it contains a nontrivial projection. Thus, in a unital, simple C*-algebras without nontrivial projections (such as the Jiang-Su algebra), at least the spectrum of every normal element is connected.

Comment: @HannesThiel  Thank you for the comment. So my second question leads to the following: What is  an example of  a projectionless  simple  $C^{*}$ algebra for which the spectrum of all elements are **path** connected.

Comment: Hannes' observation can be improved: all elements of a C*-algebra with no non-trivial projections have connected spectrum. Indeed given an element with disconnected spectrum the holomorphic functional calculus gives a non-trivial idempotent. This will be similar to some self-adjoint idempotent (see Blackadar's K-Theory book) which will be non-trivial.

Comment: Example of a connected C∗ algebra :

See B.E. Blackadar. A simple unital projectionless C∗-algebra. J. Operator Theory, 5:63–71, 1981.

By the comments of Hannes Thiel and Sam Evington this algebra is an example of a connected C* algebra.

But is it also path connected (remark by Ali Taghavi) ?

Comment: @AliTaghavi What is your motivation to consider path connected and not just connected spectra?

Comment: @HannesThiel  Thank you very much for your  comment  and your attention. The motivation for the second part of  my question, about the reduced $C^*$ algebra, is obvious. Regarding the first part: the motivation is that the product topology of two path connected space is  a path connected space. But according to your comment, one can ask that: Is the tensor product of two idempotent less C* algebras, an idempotent less C* algebra?

Comment: @JohannesHahn  Thanks  for  your  comment. As you pointed out a minimal dynamical system gives  a simple  C*  algebra. But what  about the spectrum of its  elements(Path  connected spectrum)?