# A spectral characterization of path connected spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Haussdorf topological space with the following property:

For every continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ the image $f(X)$ is a path connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Is such a space $X$ necessarilly a path connected space?

This question is inspired by (and realated to) the following post:

[Unital $C^{*}$ algebras whose all elements have path connected spectrum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195900/unital-c-algebras-whose-all-elements-have-path-connected-spectrum)

Comment: I think the extended long line $\bar L$ (add one point at each end) is a counterexample. Every map $\bar L \to \mathbf R$ (or to $\mathbf C = \mathbf R^2$) is eventually constant so the image is path connected, but $\bar L$ itself is too long to be path connected.

Comment: The one-point compactification of $\omega_1\times [0,1)$ with the order topology is indeed a counterexample. This question might be more interesting with an extra hypothesis on $X$, e.g. sequential, first countable, or metrizable.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas What about metrizable counterexamples?

Comment: @TarasBanakh That is the question I would ask...As stated, the question is answered. I cannot tell if the OP is satisfied or wants other cases addressed. My comment is meant to encourage the OP to revise the question. I will consider thinking about it more when I know what the revised question really is.